# responsive design modes seem to fail

Tags: responsive-design

I created a website for a customer: https://marie-gon.com
As always I tested it for various screen sizes using Firefox, Safari and Chrome inbuild responsive design tools.

I own a macbook 11inch, and ipad and iPhone 5/SE so for those devices I can check if the tests are the same in real live.

My customer has a macbook 16 inch retina, her partner a macbook 13inch and her graphic designer an iMac 5k retina. All 3 see sent me screen shots and none of them reflect the test results. I am trying to figure out for weeks now what's wrong and I can't solve the problem.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please read the FAQ [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/215552)

Comment: In this case that's not applicable, thank you

Comment: You've given us no code except for a link to your web site. I'd say it's pretty spot on... There is no way to solve this problem except to visit the web site using the devices listed.

Answer (score -1):

It appears all is well, except for the customer.
Probably something to do with settings of the device.